# Isomorphism between those two Algebras

Tags: exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

Why is there isomorphism between Clifford Algebra and Exterior Algebra? Maybe, better said, what does it mean to have isomorphism between those two Algebras?

Comment: At least when the field underlying a given f.d. vector space has characteristic not $2$, there is a natural vector space isomorphism between $\Lambda^{\bullet} V$ and $Cl(V, Q)$ (in characteristic $2$, there is still an isomorphism for dimensional reasons, but there is not always a natural one). This is *not*, however, an algebra isomorphism unless the quadratic form $Q$ defining the Clifford algebra is zero.

Comment: Thanks for your input Travis. Ah, yes, I have read that on Wikipedia. However, I might have wanted to know how is this applicable. How did people conclude that this isomorphism exists? I am having sort of difficulty illustrating this isomorphism in my mind. @Travis

Comment: Well, they're isomorphic simply because both spaces have dimension $2^{\dim V}$. An explicit construction of the canonical isomorphism is given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Relation_to_the_exterior_algebra .

Comment: Also, I should perhaps be more precise about my first statement: There is a canonical vector space isomorphism between the underlying vector spaces of the two algebras if $\operatorname{char} \Bbb F \neq 2$ and $Q \neq 0$. There is an algebra isomorphism between the two algebras iff $Q = 0$.

Comment: Checking again the Wiki page, it says, "The easiest way to establish the isomorphism is to choose an orthogonal basis ${e_i}$ for $V$ and extend it to a basis for $Cℓ(V, Q)$ as described above. The map $Cℓ(V, Q) → Λ(V)$ is determined by

$e_{i_1}e_{i_2}\cdots e_{i_k} \mapsto e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k}.$ What is explicit about this construction? I did not get it. @Travis

Comment: This is explicit because because the elements $e_{i_1} \cdots e_{i_k}$ comprise a basis for $Cl(V, Q)$, and to specify a linear map it suffices to specify the images of the vectors in any basis.

Comment: Yea, but how do $e_{i_1}...e_{i_k}$ go to $e_{i_1}\wedge ...\wedge e_{i_k}$? How's that possible? @Travis

Comment: Given vector spaces $\Bbb V, \Bbb W$, we can specify a linear map $T: \Bbb V, \Bbb W$ by picking a basis $(E_a)$ of $\Bbb V$ and specifying the vectors $T(E_a) \in \Bbb W$ for all $a$. Conversely, any such assignment determines a linear map.